# Looping dynamically over array of structs

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, struct, coldfusion-10

I have a shopping cart array of structs running and im trying to dynamically get the data to the screen.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(session.shoppingcart)#" index="idx">
    <cfloop collection="#session.shoppingcart[idx]#" item="key">
    <cfset mydata = session.shoppingcart[idx][key] >
    #key# #mydata# #session.shoppingcart[idx][key]#   
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

When I set the mydata variable, i am able to simply apply #mydata# to the page and it displays.

When i try to apply `#session.shoppingcart[idx][key]#` to the page i get an error stating that it cannot display this as a simple value.

Any ideas on how to get this information to display on screen ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that if you output just `#mydata#`, then it renders fine, but if you output just `#session.shoppingcart[idx][key]#` then you get an error? Can you add the *exact* error message (ie: copy and paste it from the screen) to your question. Yuo are also not telling us something or not including all the code because - from your code - `mydata` and  `session.shoppingcart[idx][key]` have exactly the same values. So will - accordingly - render the same. What have you not told us / not included?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like `session.shoppingcart[idx][key]` is an object of some sort. You can use `<cfdump var="#session.shoppingcart[idx][key]#">` to see the keys and values in that object.